# How can I make a function run in the background without blocking my entire program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some difficulties into making this function running in the background without blocking my entire program, how can I run that function in loop, without blocking my entire program?
This is the function:
    while True:
       schedule.run_pending()

Thank you for any reply.

**Edit:**

```
def FunctioninLoop():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

async def MyFunction():
    ScheduleToexecute=schedule.every().minute.do(Functionscheduled)
    t = Thread(target=FunctioninLoop())
    t.start()
    print("The execution is going on")
```

Comment: Have you looked into `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 3):

***Threads*** are what you are looking for.
Consider the following code:

```py
from threading import Thread

def myfunc(a, b, c):
    pass

# Creates a thread
t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(1, 2, 3))

# Launches the thread (while not blocking the main execution)
t.start()

somecode
somecode
somecode

# Waits for the thread to return (not a must)
t.join()
```

Hope I've helped! :)

Comment: Thank you, but after the start my program is still waiting for the loop to end

Answer (score 1):

```
import threading
pender = threading.thread(schedule.run_pending) # Does not Block
print("life goes on until...")
pender.join()                 # Blocks until schedule.run_pending() is complete.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to block the execution till the operation is complete since I need it to runs all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's subprocess module

https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html

```
import os

def myfunction():
    ..........


 os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, myfunction())
```