# How to run `selenium-chromedriver` in multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, multiprocessing, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `selenium` and `chrome-driver` to **scrape** data from some pages and then run some additional tasks with that information (for example, type some comments on some pages)

My program has a button. Every time it's pressed it calls the `thread_(self)` (bellow), starting a new thread. The target function `self.main` has the code to run all the selenium work on a `chrome-driver`.

```
def thread_(self):
    th = threading.Thread(target=self.main)
    th.start()
```

My problem is that after the user press the first time. This `th` thread will open browser **A** and do some stuff. While browser **A** is doing some stuff, the user will press the button again and open browser **B** that runs the same `self.main`. *I want each browser opened to run simultaneously.*  The problem I faced is that when I run that thread function, the first browser stops and the second browser is opened.

I know my code can create threads infinitely. And I know that this will affect the pc performance but I am ok with that. ***I want to speed up the work done*** by `self.main`!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a function run in the background without blocking my entire program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778753/how-can-i-make-a-function-run-in-the-background-without-blocking-my-entire-progr)

Comment: no it doesn't,.

Comment: but it is close

Comment: do you want to create Synchronizing Threads with the same thread function with some button ideas so that it can go like multithreading?

Comment: yes, sth like this

Comment: > but how can I open a new thread? you already wrote it `th = threading.Thread(target=self.main)
    th.start()`. Or it's not clear what you want. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying to open totally new thread while a this thread is already opened

Comment: look, I am trying to make each browser opened to run simultaneously.

Comment: why cant you just repeat this piece of code `th = threading.Thread(target=self.main)     th.start()`? Again read how to ask. You are not being clear. That's a principle: if you cannot explain what you are trying to do no one will be able to help you properly. Please read how to ask.

Comment: ok, this is what I want exactly, the user will open 'th' thread, it will open browser 'A' and do some stuff, while browser A is doing some stuff, the user will press the start button again and open browser B and do that same stuff, I want both of them to run together, the problem I faced is that when I run that thread function, the first browser stops and the second browser is opened

Comment: this is with details, sorry if I made it long

Comment: Do you get what I mean ?

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro can you please refer to my detailed question.

Comment: @Flu_PyDeveloper one more question. What exact task are you doing with selenium chrome webdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Threading` for `selenium` speed up

Consider the following functions to exemplify how threads with selenium give some speed-up compared to a single driver approach. The code bellow *scraps* the html title from a page opened by selenium using `BeautifulSoup`. The list of pages is `links`.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import threading

def create_driver():
   """returns a new chrome webdriver"""
   chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless") # make it not visible, just comment if you like seeing opened browsers
   return webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)  

def get_title(url, webdriver=None):  
   """get the url html title using BeautifulSoup 
   if driver is None uses a new chrome-driver and quit() after
   otherwise uses the driver provided and don't quit() after"""
   def print_title(driver):
      driver.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
      item = soup.find('title')
      print(item.string.strip())

   if webdriver:
      print_title(webdriver)  
   else: 
      webdriver = create_driver()
      print_title(webdriver)   
      webdriver.quit()

links = ["https://www.amazon.com", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.youtube.com/", "https://www.facebook.com/", "https://www.wikipedia.org/", 
"https://us.yahoo.com/?p=us", "https://www.instagram.com/", "https://www.globo.com/", "https://outlook.live.com/owa/"]
```

Calling now `get_tile` on the `links` above.

**Sequential approach**

A single chrome driver and passing all links sequentially. Takes 22.3 s my machine (note:windows).

```
start_time = time.time()
driver = create_driver()

for link in links: # could be 'like' clicks 
  get_title(link, driver)  

driver.quit()
print("sequential took ", (time.time() - start_time), " seconds")
```

**Multiple threads approach**

Using a thread for each link. Results in 10.5 s > 2x faster.

```
start_time = time.time()    
threads = [] 
for link in links: # each thread could be like a new 'click' 
    th = threading.Thread(target=get_title, args=(link,))    
    th.start() # could `time.sleep` between 'clicks' to see whats'up without headless option
    threads.append(th)        
for th in threads:
    th.join() # Main thread wait for threads finish
print("multiple threads took ", (time.time() - start_time), " seconds")
```

[This here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387309/multithreading-in-python-selenium) and [this better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53475578/1207193) are some other working examples. The second uses a fixed number of threads on a `ThreadPool`. And suggests that storing the `chrome-driver` instance initialized on each thread is faster than creating-starting it every time.

Still I was not sure this was the optimal approach for selenium *to have considerable speed-ups.* Since [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) on [no IO bound code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python?rq=1) will end-up [executed sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3044580/1207193) (one thread after another). Due the Python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) a Python process cannot run threads in parallel (utilize multiple cpu-cores).

### `Processes` for `selenium` speed up

To try to overcome the Python GIL limitation using the package [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [`Processes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) class I wrote the following code and I ran multiple tests. I even added random page hyperlink clicks on the `get_title` function above. [Additional code is here.](https://gist.github.com/eusoubrasileiro/db756605e1544061b20cdba3d383f766)

```
start_time = time.time() 

processes = [] 
for link in links: # each thread a new 'click' 
    ps = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_title, args=(link,))    
    ps.start() # could sleep 1 between 'clicks' with `time.sleep(1)``
    processes.append(ps)        
for ps in processes:
    ps.join() # Main wait for processes finish

return (time.time() - start_time)
```

*Contrary to what I expected,* **Python `multiprocessing.Process`** based parallelism for `selenium` in average **was around 8% slower than `threading.Thread`.** But obviously both were in average more than twice faster than the sequential approach. Just found out that `selenium` chrome-driver commands uses `HTTP-Requets` (like `POST`, `GET`) so it is I/O bounded therefore it releases the Python GIL indeed making it parallel in threads.

### `Threading` a good start for `selenium` speed up **

**This is not a definitive answer** as my tests were only a tiny example. Also I'm using Windows and `multiprocessing` have many limitations in this case. Each new `Process` is not a fork like in Linux meaning, among other downsides, a lot of memory is wasted.

**Taking all that in account:** It seems that, depending on the use case, threads maybe as good or better than trying the heavier approach of using processes (specially for Windows users).

Comment: I am looking forward for that approach

Comment: @Flu_PyDeveloper one more question. What exact task are you doing with selenium chrome webdriver? That needs to be reapeated again and again. Is it headless?

Comment: Is some kind of scrapping or just open a page and walking through it?

Comment: do you need the result of those background threads?

Comment: open a page and getting some data, but I need to speed up things, so I think of opening more than one browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236601/discussion-between-eusoubrasileiro-and-flu-py-developer).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def thread_(self):
    th = threading.Thread(target=self.main)
    self.jobs.append(th)
    th.start()
```

info: https://pymotw.com/2/threading/